# Problems with system:admin login after changing to HTPasswd Identity Provider in Openshift Origin

Tags: configuration, .htpasswd, openshift-origin

Wanting to switch to HTPasswd Identity provider i have updated the master-config.yaml to look like this

```
identityProviders:
  - name: my_htpasswd_provider 
  challenge: true 
  login: true 
  provider:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider
    file: /path/to/users.htpasswd
```

Im using the oc cluster:
*oc cluster up --host-data-dir=/opt/openshift_data --host-config-dir=/opt/openshift_conf --use-existing-config* 
, but when i try to log in with the system:admin user this happens.

```
oc login -u system:admin
The server uses a certificate signed by an unknown authority.
You can bypass the certificate check, but any data you send to the server  could be intercepted by others.
Use insecure connections? (y/n): y

Login failed (401 Unauthorized)
You must obtain an API token by visiting https://:8443/oauth/token/request
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error, when I changed the authentication provider of my Openshift cluster, and I had already logged in as admin user with the old authentication provider settings.

I had to add **mappingMethod: add** option to my configuration, so It could map the existing user.

```
identityProviders:
  - challenge: true
    login: true
    mappingMethod: add
    name: my_htpasswd_provider
    provider:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider
      file: /var/openshift/users.htpasswd
```

This is Openshift documentation url:

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#mapping-identities-to-users

Hope this helps